# Is there a way to mark a bean as not primary in Spring?

Tags: spring

I am having two beans in different packages out of which one of them is a library so cannot edit,  and execution gives the

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '' available:`

For current purpose I want the bean in the library to be the primary bean, is there a way to avoid using the second bean which i can edit , without deleting the bean?

So far have only seen the @Primary annotation

Answer (score -1):

when spring is trying to inject the dependency it found to to beans for it .
so you have add @Qualifier annotation and give the corresponding class in it which you want to inject